# Having trouble installing guest additions for a Xubuntu 13.10 guest OS in Virtualbox 4.2.10

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, 13.10, guest-additions

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 64-BIT as my **host** operating system running Virtual Box 4.2.10. I  get this message when I tell virtualbox to install guest additions(CTRL+D),mounting the volume in the guest OS and run the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run file using root by:

```
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

It starts and then comes to these error messages:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 4.2.10 Guest Additions for Linux..........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

    Building the main Guest Additions module ...done.
    Building the shared folder support module ...fail!
    (Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
    Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
    Installing the Window System drivers
    Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed.  Not installing
    X Window System drivers.
    Installing modules ...done.
    Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.
    allusers@allusers-VirtualBox:/media/allusers/VBOXADDITIONS_4.2.10_84104$
```

I followed everything from the [official VirtualBox manual on installing guest additions for linux](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)
I used some other commands such as:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

I rebooted after executing those command and it still wont work. It still says the kernel modules are missing and the window is not seamless. Any idea what could be the problem?
Here is the log file [vboxadd-install.log](http://pastebin.com/5zu7ADtm)

Comment: What `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log` says?

Comment: I have edited my message to show the link to the log Braiam

Comment: Did you ran `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup`?

Comment: Yes and it still says" The headers for the current kernel are not found. If the following module compilation fails then this could be the problem."

Comment: Did you restart the system? Try installing `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)-generic` instead.

Comment: Braiam. The problem is resolved by installing the 4.3 version of virtualbox from Oracle's site. I thought I had the official one installed and used(and it was 4.2). It was the one in the repository. It was outdated and had many bugs. I installed the guest additions and everything worked fine(In the oracle 4.3 version) even drag and drop started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've been running the same problem on Debian Wheezy host, running VirtualBox 4.1.8 (with Kubuntu 13.10 as guest).

After some diggings, it seems that installing guest additions on recent 13.10 derived Linux distributions (such as yours : Xubuntu 13.10) requires at least version 4.3 of VirtualBox run on the host.

To update your VirtualBox version up to 4.3:

Add the official repository to your /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib
```

Add the official Oracle repository key and update your repositories list:

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Select any running virtualbox daemons' id:

```
ps -aux | grep virtualbox
```

and kill them.

Install the new version of VirtualBox (it will automatically remove the previous version)

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

Launch your guest from the VirtualBox interface and install the Guest Additions from the 4.3 .iso on your Linux 13.10 guest, the same way as you did (**sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run**). The kernel module will find the appropriate linux header for compilation.

Hope this helps.

For information, here's the [generic linux distribution installation tutorial for VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)